# generate xsd and set fields as required in JAX-WS

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws

[image: Request description]

The following is an implementation of the specification outlined in the above picture.

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface WithdrawService {

    @WebMethod
    public Response withdraw(
            @WebParam(name="CORPCODE") String corpcode,
            @WebParam(name="SERVCODE") String servcode, 
            @WebParam(name="AMOUNT") double amount, 
            @WebParam(name="CCYID") String ccyid, 
            @WebParam(name="ACCTNO") String acctno, 
            @WebParam(name="REFVAL1") String refvel1, 
            @WebParam(name="REFVAL2") String refval2, 
            @WebParam(name="TRANREF") String tranref, 
            @WebParam(name="DESC") String desc, 
            @WebParam(name="LICENSEID") String licenseid, 
            @WebParam(name="LICENSEKEY") String licensekey
            );

}
```

The following WSDL is generated when a user accesses the `?wsdl` link.

```
<!-- Published by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.10 svn-revision#919b322c92f13ad085a933e8dd6dd35d4947364b. 
-->
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.10 svn-revision#919b322c92f13ad085a933e8dd6dd35d4947364b. 
-->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://withdraw.kbz.nirvasoft.com/" name="WithdrawServiceImplService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://withdraw.kbz.nirvasoft.com/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WithdrawService/withdraw?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="withdraw">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:withdraw"/>
    </message>
    <message name="withdrawResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:withdrawResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="WithdrawService">
        <operation name="withdraw">
            <input wsam:Action="http://withdraw.kbz.nirvasoft.com/WithdrawService/withdrawRequest" message="tns:withdraw"/>
            <output wsam:Action="http://withdraw.kbz.nirvasoft.com/WithdrawService/withdrawResponse" message="tns:withdrawResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="WithdrawServiceImplPortBinding" type="tns:WithdrawService">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="withdraw">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="WithdrawServiceImplService">
        <port name="WithdrawServiceImplPort" binding="tns:WithdrawServiceImplPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/WithdrawService/withdraw"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

We are unhappy with two things.

1. We do not get any xsd documents for the types used.
2. We cannot say whether fields are required in the generated wsdl.

I would like to know how we could achieve them using our code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your XSD from
http://localhost:8080/WithdrawService/withdraw?xsd=1

Depending on the server you use you can ask JAX-WS to generate embedded XSD file. Alternatively you can ask JAX-WS to use you own WSDL.